# GitlabCi slow build with docker and mysql service

Tags: php, docker, phpunit, gitlab-ci

I´m using gitlab-ci-multirunner 9.3.0 and the GitLab Community Edition 9.3.5

When i´m running my php-unit test on my local virtual box environment, the total test (30) just need about:

```
Time: 5 minutes, Memory: 96.00MB
```

Running the same tests on my gitlab host, it needs a total of

```
Time: 41.68 minutes, Memory: 97.75MB
```

The tests require mysql and do a database create and fixture load on each test.

My DockerFile:

```
FROM tetraweb/php:5.6

# Install additional packages
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get -qq upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -qq -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -qq -y mysql-client libmagickwand-dev libgeoip-dev -y --no-install-recommends
RUN pecl install imagick apcu-4.0.11 geoip
RUN docker-php-ext-enable exif gd gettext intl mcrypt mysql mysqli opcache pdo_mysql zip memcache apcu imagick geoi
```

my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
  TIMEZONE: Europe/Berlin
  MYSQL_DATABASE: test
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test-root
  MYSQL_USER: test
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: asecurething
  SYMFONY_ENV: "test"

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test:
  image: test-image-php:5.6
  services:
    - mariadb:latest
  stage: test
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
  script:
      - export COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=x/cache/composer
      - SYMFONY_ENV=test composer install --no-progress --no-interaction
      - chmod +x bin/console
      - php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
```

I really think thats the mysql service fault who creates the big difference. 
Whats the best way to increase the performance of my phpunit tests?

Comment: Running a database server inside docker is - even if technically possible - most often degrading the whole service - if not breaking it (you will loose fundamental characteristics of the database server you want to rely on, like ACID or *performance*). For your tests this must not be. Consider to mock the whole database layer so that in a testing environment it's just not necessary any longer. This should also speed-up your tests and make them working again usefully in a containerized environment.

Comment: So you would recommend 1) a external db server on a real host or 2) another struct for testing?

Comment: by the way - running the same test on a docker on my mac host, the tests "just" needs 15 minutes.

Comment: If you aim to achieve 15m with the CI system, check i/o,load+mem on that system and foster it with the needed resources. I didn't recommend a single thing with my comment, just that you can do different parts here to achieve a better runtime, e.g. externalizing the DB could be what you're looking for or if that breaks your modularisation increase system performance and/or change the testing strategy.

Answer (score 5):

I am using gitlab-ci 10.3.0 where my tests on the server took 40 minutes but on the Mac took 2 minutes. The server outspecs the Mac except for the hard disk where the Mac is using SSD.

Not sure if appropriate solution but I modified my runner configs to match the one in [Docker Executor - Mounting a directory in RAM](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#mounting-a-directory-in-ram).

I have added the following in the config.toml:

```
[runners.docker]
# For the main container
[runners.docker.tmpfs]
    "/var/lib/mysql" = "rw,noexec"

# For services
[runners.docker.services_tmpfs]
    "/var/lib/mysql" = "rw,noexec"
```

I managed to reduce the build time to 2 minutes as well on the server.

Comment: Nice - thanks! Will try it and provide feedback.
How did you achived the 2 min on your macbook. Docker (compose) and a separate mysql container is slow, too.

Comment: I just installed the gitlab-runner on the macbook and let it run similar to the server. The time difference was too large so I thought the slowness is because of the 7200 RPM hard disk.